# Why can't wxwidgets and sfml play nice?

Tags: c++, gtk, wxwidgets, sfml

I want to use sfml with wxwidgets. I tried to follow a rather dated tutorial because there isn't a more recent one.

Tutorials here: http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-wxwidgets.php

The tutorial is for sfml1.6 and wxwidgets 2.x however I want to use sfml2.1 with wxwidgets 3 but the code wont compile. Apparently win_gtk.h is now a private header and unaccessible in gtk3? This header contains gtk_pizza. As for the display() error I have no idea what's wrong there... Anyway to make everything play nice?

Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <wx/wx.h>

#ifdef __WXGTK__
    #include <gdk/gdkx.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    // #include <wx/gtk/win_gtk.h> this doesn't exist in wxwidgets3?
#endif


class wxSFMLCanvas : public wxControl, public sf::RenderWindow
{
public :

    wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent = NULL, wxWindowID Id = -1, const wxPoint& Position = wxDefaultPosition,
                 const wxSize& Size = wxDefaultSize, long Style = 0);

    virtual ~wxSFMLCanvas();

private :

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()

    virtual void OnUpdate();

    void OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&);

    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&);

    void OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent&);
};

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&)
{
    // Send a paint message when the control is idle, to ensure maximum framerate
    Refresh();
}

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    // Prepare the control to be repainted
    wxPaintDC Dc(this);

    // Let the derived class do its specific stuff
    OnUpdate();

    // Display on screen
    Display();
}


wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent, wxWindowID Id, const wxPoint& Position, const wxSize& Size, long Style) :
wxControl(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style)
{
    #ifdef __WXGTK__

        // GTK implementation requires to go deeper to find the
        // low-level X11 identifier of the widget
        gtk_widget_realize(m_wxwindow);
        gtk_widget_set_double_buffered(m_wxwindow, false);
        GdkWindow* Win = GTK_PIZZA(m_wxwindow)->bin_window;
        XFlush(GDK_WINDOW_XDISPLAY(Win));
        //sf::RenderWindow::Create(GDK_WINDOW_XWINDOW(Win));

    #else

        // Tested under Windows XP only (should work with X11
        // and other Windows versions - no idea about MacOS)
        //sf::RenderWindow::Create(GetHandle());

    #endif
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
[greg@greg-desktop polyedit]$ make
g++ -g -I. -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz   -MMD -MP -c -o .eobjs/./main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In member function 'void wxSFMLCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)':
main.cpp:49:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'Display {aka struct _XDisplay}'
     Display();
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/cursor.h:69:0,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/event.h:21,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wx.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/utils.h:778:15: error: forward declaration of 'Display {aka struct _XDisplay}'
 inline struct _XDisplay *wxGetX11Display()
               ^
main.cpp: In constructor 'wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, wxWindowID, const wxPoint&, const wxSize&, long int)':
main.cpp:62:46: error: 'GTK_PIZZA' was not declared in this scope
         GdkWindow* Win = GTK_PIZZA(m_wxwindow)->bin_window
```

Comment: That's because you tried to post it as a link. Put the errors, and your code, directly in your post.

Comment: @user1953923 Check this [markup help section](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) please, and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is indeed out of date and it was never a good idea to use private wxGTK headers and implementation details in any case. I don't know anything about SFML, but you need to find out what exactly is the native `WindowHandle` described in its documentation and then you should be able to get it from wxGTK.

FYI `m_wxwindow` is a `GtkFixed` which itself is a `GtkContainer` which is a `GtkWidget`, so if you can find out how to use SFML with native `GtkContainer` or `GtkWidget`, you should be able to use it with wxGTK as well without too many problems.

Good luck!